# What is the time complexity of this top down dynamic programming code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, dynamic-programming

I can't analyze time complexity of top down dynamic programming approach like below example. Can you please help me?

> Problem : Given a string s and a dictionary of strings wordDict, return true if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words. Note that the same word in the dictionary may be reused multiple times in the segmentation.
>
> Input: `s = "catsandog"`, `wordDict = ["cats","dog","sand","and","cat"]`
> Output: `false`
>
> Input: `s = "leetcode"`, `wordDict = ["leet","code"]`
> Output: `true`

```
bool match(string &s,int l,int n,string &wordDict) {
    int i = 0;
    while(l < n && i < wordDict.size()) {
        if (s[l] != wordDict[i])
            return false;
        l++;
        i++;
    }
    return i == wordDict.size();
}
bool wordBreakUtil(string &s, int l, int n, vector<string>& wordDict, map<int,bool> &m) {
    if (l==n)
        return true;
    if (m.find(l) != m.end()) {
        return m[l];
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<wordDict.size();i++) {
        if (match(s,l,n,wordDict[i])) {
            if (wordBreakUtil(s,l+wordDict[i].size(),n,wordDict,m))
                return true;
        }
    }
    m[l] = false;
    return false;
}
bool wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {
    int n = s.size();
    map<int,bool> m;
    return wordBreakUtil(s,0,n,wordDict,m);
}
```

Comment: What is your problem in analyzing the complexity? If you call an O(log n) function k times, that has the overall complexity of O(k log n). As a suggestion, extract the algorithm (in pseudocode) from this code first, then analyze its complexity.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  what is k and n in your answer? what is O(logn) function in your answer? Note that there are recursive calls in this function?

Comment: Constants like k and n typically hold a count, like the number of elements in a sequence. Please, make sure you demonstrate an effort in solving this.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Analyzing string algorithm like this can be tricky (at least for me), it might not be as easy as it seems. (if you want to find a tight upper bound). However, I agree that OP should show their attempt first.

Comment: let say original string length is n. there are k words in dictionary. each word has an average length L.  worst case happens when each dictionary word present as prefix of the  input string. Let T(n) is the total run time.   So when wordBreakUtil() is called first time it will match each word and for each recursively smaller then is called. So 
T(n) = L * T(n-L) | + L * T(n-L) + L * T(n-L) .... + L * T(n-L)// k times
so T(n) = k*L*T(n-L) 
let say n = p *L
so above recurrence equates to T(n) = k^p  * L^p.    Is it correct?

Comment: The problem is that analyzing the performance improvement of caching (memorization in this case) can be extremely difficult and indeed it is not always possible to produce a deterministic characterization of it.  In general top-down DP should always have a Big-O at least as fast as its bottom-up equivalent (though perhaps more complicated and/or higher k-factor), but figuring out how much faster it might be can be very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A worst-case bound for memoised DP algorithms can be found by separating out the computational work done inside recursive calls from other work. Specifically we need to determine:

1. The maximum possible number of times that the recursive function gets called *with distinct inputs (parameter values)* -- this is the maximum possible number of times that the function will have to "do its job" instead of quickly returning an already-computed answer.
2. The maximum amount of work done inside each call to the recursive function, *excluding* inside recursive calls to itself.

We can then multiply the answer to (1) by the answer to (2) to get an upper bound. (This bound might not be tight, because there might be structure in the problem that means that an asymptotically important number of recursive function invocations are actually avoided, or the amount of work done inside each invocation is much less than the maximum possible in an asymptotically important fraction of these calls, or both -- but in practice it very often is tight.)

### Maximum number of distinct recursive calls

The recursive function `wordBreakUtil()` is called with 6 different parameters, but in fact only one of them, `l`, varies with each call. Because we memoise results in `m`, we are guaranteed that we only make it as far as the main body of the function (the `for` loop) when we are dealing with a value of `l` that we haven't ever seen before: This means that the answer to (1) is the maximum number of *distinct* `l` values that `wordBreakUtil()` could possibly be called with, which is just `n + 1` (the values 0, 1, 2, ..., `n`). Asymptotically this is O(n).

### Maximum amount of non-recursive work done in each call

Suppose there are `k` words in the dictionary. Within `wordBreakUtil()`, the maximum amount of work that it does, *excluding* in recursive calls to itself, is O(kn). This is because it loops `k` times, calling `match()` each time, and `match()` takes at most `n` steps in its loop. (You could alternative describe `match()`'s complexity as `L`, where `L` is the maximum length of any string in the dictionary, or you could describe it more precisely as `min(n, L)`, but adding the `L` parameter makes for a more complicated expression without contributing much information.) There's also a `log k` additive term for the `m.find(l)` call, but this is dominated by the O(kn) term, so the non-recursive work done in `wordBreakUtil()` remains O(kn).

This means that overall execution time is bounded by O(kn^2).